# Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview

I am trying to add a `BottomNavigationView` in my UI but I get the exception below:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity 
    ComponentInfo{com.appeaser.sublimepicker/com.appeaser.sublimepicker.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: 
    Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: 
    Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2817)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #0: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
 Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284)
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143)
    at com.appeaser.sublimepicker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19)
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
 Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
    at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:195)
    at android.content.res.Resources.getColorStateList(Resources.java:1019)
    at android.content.Context.getColorStateList(Context.java:622)
    at android.support.v7.content.res.AppCompatResources.getColorStateList(AppCompatResources.java:65)
    at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.createDefaultColorStateList(BottomNavigationView.java:285)
    at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:118)
    at android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView.<init>(BottomNavigationView.java:86)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:334) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:647) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:790) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:730) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:863) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:824) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:515) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:423) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplV9.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImplV9.java:284) 
    at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:143) 
    at com.appeaser.sublimepicker.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:19) 
    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6975) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1213) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2770) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2892) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1593) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:105) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:name="com.appeaser.sublimepicker.DatePickerFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/appBarLayout"/>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:src="@mipmap/app_icon"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:visibility="gone"
        app:backgroundTint="#FF0000"
        app:rippleColor="#FFF" />

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_navigation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/bottom_navigation_view_height"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:elevation="8dp"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation_main" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

build.gradle

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:25.0.0'
```

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="@string/today"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_schedules"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="@string/todo_list"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_music"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:title="@string/event_list"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />

</menu>
```

Comment: share java code

Comment: this might be because of your fragment.

Comment: Share your menu xml

Comment: @Omi There is only 1 line i.e. setContentView in my Activity class till now

Comment: @MeosCoder please see menu.xml added

Answer (score 3):

For others having the same issue and having the right versions (above 26.1.0), in my case the issue was because I was using an SVG drawable as an icon, on an API 22 device.

Answer (score 1):

I think it was added from version 26.1.0, not 25.0.0. Please refer this link:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/BottomNavigationView.html

[image]

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/18959049)

Comment: @MaximilianPeters, thank you. The essential parts of the answer is: " it was added from version 26.1.0, not 25.0.0"

Comment: Tried but still same issue/crash happenig

Comment: @VVB, have you tried to clean the project after updating gradle ?

Comment: Yes cleaned/rebuilt but still same issue

Comment: @VVB, I tested your layout, it works if I remove the fragment "com.appeaser.sublimepicker.DatePickerFragment". I cannot add it from my side although I added compile 'com.appeaser.sublimepickerlibrary:sublimepickerlibrary:2.1.1'. Hence, i think it is the problem.

Comment: Even I tried by same but not working, please share your build.gradle

Comment: Cannot post the image to comment, hence, I updated the answer to share gradle file

Answer (score 0):

As they said here

[image]

try update version `design dependency` in `gradle` file like

```
compile 'com.android.support:design:27.1.0'
```

don't forget to finally `clean` and `rebuild` project

Comment: No luck still same issue

Comment: your error also have colorState error so try to remove **android:background="@android:color/white"** or change color...

Comment: setting it to colorPrimary, let me check now

Answer (score 0):

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_favorite_white_24dp"
    android:title="@string/text_favorites"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_schedules"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_access_time_white_24dp"
    android:title="@string/text_schedules"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_music"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_audiotrack_white_24dp"
    android:title="@string/text_music"
    app:showAsAction="ifRoom" /></menu>
```

This is menu xml format.

Comment: It is same only thing is I don't need icon, skipped xmlns lines but those are in place

Comment: And <menu> and </menu> tag?

Comment: Yes everything like above