# Text view contents not appearing on the phone screen in android using Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, inflate-exception, layout-animation

I am unable to display the textviews and their contents on screen. The app does not crash but the debugger console displays this error. It shows that the causes are the following.

```
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #11: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unknown layout animation name: accelerateInterpolator
```

Moreover, the error points to `setcontentview` in the MainActivity. I have attempted solutions to the [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49024880/binary-xml-file-line-0-error-inflating-class-android-support-design-widget-bot) but to no progress. In fact I have higher version but this the error persists.

The build.gradle(Module:app) contents are

```
//noinspection GradleCompatible
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'

android {
compileSdkVersion 27
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.example.vishwa.imaginators"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
buildTypes {
    release {
        debuggable false
        shrinkResources false
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        zipAlignEnabled true
    }
  }
}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
//noinspection GradleCompatible
implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp-urlconnection:2.2.0'

//retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:adapter-rxjava2:2.3.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0'
//    implementation "com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-moshi:2.0.0"
//rxjava
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.0.1'
implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.1.7'
//download sdk
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:4.34.0'
implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-login:[4,5)'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.3.2'
}
```

The activity_main.xml is shown below.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/main"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@mipmap/bg"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="56dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_colors"
    app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_colors"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation">

</android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/main_frame"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_above="@id/bottom_nav"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview_Main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
  </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

A snippet of the code that where I am adding the contents to this fragment.

```
bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->
        when(item.itemId){
            R.id.nav_progress->
                progressData()
            R.id.nav_discover->
                discoverData(arrItems)
            R.id.nav_concept->
                fetchData(arrItems, indices)
           }
        true
    }

    private fun progressData() {

    var titles = listOf("first","second", "third","fourth")
    val text1=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.quadrant1_textview1)
    val text2=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.quadrant2_textview1)
    val text3=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.quadrant3_textview1)
    val text4=findViewById<TextView>(R.id.quadrant4_textview1)
    text1?.text=titles[0]
    text2?.text=titles[1]
    text3?.text=titles[2]
    text4?.text=titles[3]
    }
```

The ProgressData() funtion is outside the oncreate.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: check if you component with same name

Comment: @YoLo which component are you asking?

Comment: bottom navigation view also share your code for activity

Comment: @YoLo I am using bottomnavigationview. But I am using no animation. If you see the last of the causes.

Comment: please share your activity

Comment: @YoLo I have edited the question with the activity_main.xml

Comment: Clean your project and run again

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176791/discussion-between-eswar-and-yolo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem is that the view is not generated in the `onCreate` or `OnCreateview`. If we see the life-cycle of the fragment, we find that there is another method `onViewcreated`. The static code where the values are assigned to the text of the textviews must be placed in the `onViewcreated` method of the Progress fragment. This solved the problem.

The code snippet:

```
override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
    progress_progressbar2?.setProgress(12)
    progress_progressbar2?.max=15
    val currentProgress = progress_progressbar2?.progress ?: 0
    if (currentProgress == 0){
        started_image?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        progress_scrollview?.invalidate()
    } else {
        started_image?.visibility = View.GONE
        progress_scrollview?.visibility = View.VISIBLE
        navigation_header_container?.setImageResource(R.drawable.header_pink)
    }
}
```

Thankyou YoLo for support. This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Try following code hope this will help:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/main"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/main_frame"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerview_Main"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </FrameLayout>

    <android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        app:itemBackground="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/nav_item_colors"
        app:itemTextColor="@color/nav_item_colors"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_navigation">

    </android.support.design.widget.BottomNavigationView>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: You just swapped the Framelayout and the bottomnavigationview. Also changed the recyclerview height to wrap content. Well I want it to match parent.This hasn't worked.

Comment: Now it shows E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout 
E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xa2838320

Comment: Is your bottom navigation view visible now??

Comment: yes. its visible but when I tap on the icon below for which I am attempting this view. Nothing happens. No display comes. Only the contents of the activity_main.xml are shown. Nothing from this fragment. Please see the question I have edited to include the snippet of code where I am assigning the text and calling the function. The ProgressData() funtion is not displaying anything.

Comment: share your methods

Comment: Only the progressData function is giving problem of giving no display and I have shared that method. Moreover, the I have checked that the method is entered using Log.i(). When I put a log to print the text value, it says null. It says that text1 is null.

Comment: "$text1?.text" returns null inspite of assigning a string as you can see in the method.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176796/discussion-between-eswar-and-yolo).

Comment: What I want cannot be achieved because I was using fragments to display the data. I was using the adapter directly in the mainactivity. Now I have shifting to using fragments and figured out that it wont work if I have recyclerview in the activity_main.xml and want to replace it with scrollview. It might work if I disable the recyclerview and then use scrollview. Well, instead I shifted to a fragmented approach, now the problem is nearly solved.